# "antcall must not be used at the top level" error using Ant-Contrib <foreach>

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am getting the following error when executing the Ant script further below:

> antcall must not be used at the top level

I am using the Jenkins Active Choices Plug-in and passing a parameter to the Ant script.

```
<project name="svncheckout" default="checkout" basedir=".">
    <path id="svnant.classpath">
        <pathelement location="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/svnClientAdapter.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/ganymed.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/jna.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/svnant.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/svnjavahl.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/svnkit.jar"/>
    </path>

    <!-- Load the ant contrib lib -->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/ant-lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <loadproperties srcFile="/opt/Tomcat/apache-ant-1.9.6/chkout.properties"/>
    <property name="applist" value="${env.Applns_List}"/>

    <foreach list="${applist}"
                    delimiter=","
                    target="checkout"
                    param="appl.id" />

    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" /> 

    <svnSetting
            svnkit="true"
            javahl="false"
            username="xxx"
            password="xxx"
            id="svn.settings"/>  

    <target name="checkout"  description="checkout code"> 
        <forEach property="application" list="${applist}" delimiter=","> 
            <sequential>  
                <svn refid="svn.settings" >
                    <checkout url="${application}.url"
                          destPath="/opt/tibco/DeploymentFramework/checkout/"  />
                </svn>
            </sequential>
        </forEach>
    </target>
</project>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Ant-Contrib [`<foreach>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) cannot be used at the top level of an Ant script.

Instead, `<foreach>` must be inside of a `<target>`...

```
<!-- Change the default target from "checkout" to "run" -->
<project name="svncheckout" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <!-- This <foreach> is now inside of a <target> -->
        <foreach list="${applist}"
            delimiter=","
            target="checkout"
            param="appl.id" />
    </target>

    <target name="checkout">
        <echo>appl.id is: ${appl.id}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```